# How to display checkstyle violations generated through maven build in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want the check style violations generated through maven build in Eclipse IDE (using external maven) like how your java file get published with checkstyle violations when you do "check code with checkstyle".

I can run my files explicitly with eclipse checkstyle plugins but my project requirement is to run with maven build.

Is there a way to achieve this? I couldn't find any links regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do that through Sonar, which is running checkstyle. I installed Sonar locally and added the following profile to my maven project (you could also add it to your personal ~ /.m2/settings.xml):

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:7080/sonar</sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Now, you can run Sonar on your project with:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Psonar
```

[In Eclipse, you need to install the Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+Sonar+in+Eclipse/). It allows you to either run a local analysis directly in Eclipse or retrieve the outcome of a remote one. In both cases, violations and problems are added to the Eclipse warnings/message dialog so that you can follow up easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sebi. But we are not using sonar in our project and the requirement is like the violations should get reflected java files instead of adding them to the Eclipse warnings/message dialog. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: @user1450913 In the Sonar approach, the violations found are shown directly in the file editor and the message dialog.